# How to setup docker containers for 2 applications

Tags: laravel, reactjs, docker

I have two teams first one writing backend on laravel second team writong front on react. How better  orginize docker container. create 1 container for 2 projects or create 2 different containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think creating 2 containers is better:

- You have your frontend completely seperated from your backend.
- You can redeploy your frontend / backend without the other part (only update frontend / only update backend)
- Your deploys are smaller
- Bugs should be easier to find (Was that system error in container A or B?)
- You can easier replace a container, for example when you want to show a maintenance screen while the api is running in the background. (replace the frontend container with the maintenance container e.g.)
- You can build, run and test only the frontend / only the backend and don't need both parts at anytime

But this only works when your react application is standalone (what it is if it's a react application), that means it should work "by itself" and only consume the API (REST / GraphQL / WebSocket) of the backend.

However, there are also some things to keep track of:

- If you make a breaking change to the interface (API etc.) you have to deploy both containers at once to prevent incompatibility errors / downtime

Comment: What about images from backend. I can create WraperCOmponent and from enviroment variable get BASE_URL to backend and add this url to image. Is it good practice?

Comment: And what about ports i can setup nginx for React component in docker  on 80 port. what about backend.